# Apps Script on Goog Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried multiple scripts but none worked out...trying to get goog sheets to fire off email alerts (sheet link below)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QKh6OJ1JV401tKh7QggoWpNz4Sfi0ppjHXwSPF8kf4E/edit?usp=sharing

2 alerts needed:

> 1. send email to XXXX@yyy.com w Mesg ” Trigger” when  Col C value is lower than Col D or Higher than Col E.
> 2. also email XXXX@yyy.com with mesg "Trigger reachd"  when Col C value is Higher than (Col I * Col F) or Lower than (Col H * Col G).

Also- someone suggested use of Time Based triggers..I guess to let goog sheet open and functions like GoogFinance & CryptoFinancere run and refresh data. Can the functions update on backend even if the sheet is not open in any browser? How can I acheive that? because I dont want to keep this sheet open on a browser all the time.

How can I do this from a script? Could you offer some suggestion? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Try using [time based triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a script that compares 2 cells against criteria and if it meets the criteria runs a section of code that sends an email. Here
is an example that does not match your criteria or model, but is a starting point for how you might go about coding your solution:

```
function compareCells() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var strc="A1"; //1st cell to evaluate
    var strv="A2"; //2nd cell to evaluate
    if (sheet.getRange(strc).getValue()>sheet.getRange(strv).getValue()) { //checks if A1 > A2


           MailApp.sendEmail('XXXX@yyy.com', emailSubject, 'Trigger reachd');

    }
  }
```

Once you find a script that works for your situation click on the  [image] icon and set your trigger up like so:

[image]

Anytime your spreadsheet changes, even if it is closed, it will run the script and and fire an email if the criteria is met. Hope this helps - best of luck.